# EF 4.1 Code First Detaching Entity

Tags: entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I am trying to add an entity to the DB. Once I have added it, I want to detach it, so I can manipulate the object safely without making any changes to the DB. After calling `context.SaveChanges()` I do the following to detach the entity:

```
    // save
    context.Stories.Add(story);

    // attach tags. They already exists in the database    
    foreach(var tag in story.Tags)
      context.Entry(tag).State = System.Data.EntityState.Unchanged;

    context.SaveChanges();

    context.Entry(story).State = System.Data.EntityState.Detached;
```

However, changing the entity state to DETACHED will remove all related entities associated with the my entity. Is there a way to stop this ?

If I don't detach the entity, all my changes are sent to the DB next time I call `context.SaveChanges()`

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way. It is limitation of EF. Your options are:

- Not using the same context for another save (single context instance = single save)
- Retrieve the entity from database again using another context instance which will not be used for saving
- Create deep clone of your entity and use the clonned one (deep clone is done by serialization and immediate deserialization = your entity graph must be serializable)

Comment: Thanks. I created a clone of the entity and used the cloned one.

Comment: Retrieving the entity again is not efficient at all. Using a different context is not easy either.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two ways to approach this problem:

- Purist: retrieving entities from a DbContext and modifying them without saving is a misuse of the tools and the architecture. Use a DTO instead.
- Pragmatic: you can use `AsNoTracking()` to retrieve an entity graph that will not be tracked by the context for changes.

Comment: AsNoTracking() is for retrieving, not for adding entities. Modifying entities without saving is not a misuse. Sometimes, you need to tweak values in the presentation layer without saving to the DB.

Comment: OK, I didn't read the first part correctly. Still, "tweaking values in the presentation layer" is what a ViewModel is for.